# Why doesn't the menu in this Python program function?

Tags: python-2.7, menu

I have looked over this code 100 times and I feel like it may be something small that I am missing. Program will allow you to login, and display the menu but after entering your selection it continuously displays the menu again.

```
 import sys

def main():
    login = 'yes'
    choice = 0
    hours = [0] * 7
    wages = 0
    totalHours = 0
    totalWages = 0
    print
    login = raw_input('Do you want to login?')
    while not (login == 'yes' or login == 'no'):
        print
        print 'Please enter a yes or no'
    while login == 'yes':
        print
        userId = raw_input ('Enter user name:')
        passWord = raw_input('Enter password:')
        while passWord != userId:
            print 'Incorrect Password, please try again.'
            passWord = raw_input('Enter password:')
        while passWord == userId:
            print 'Login Success!'
            print
            print 'Enter 1 to view upcoming schedule'
            print 'Enter 2 to view previous schedule'
            print 'Enter 3 to calculate wages due'
            print 'Enter 4 to verify clock in/out times'
            print
            choice = raw_input('Enter 1 to 4 from menu.')

def readFromNext(nextWeek):
    inFile = open('nextweek.txt', 'r')
    str1 = inFile.read()
    print str1
    str2 = inFile.read()
    print str2
    print
    inFile.close()

def readFromLast(lastWeek):
    inFile = open('lastweek.txt', 'r')
    str1 = inFile.read()
    print str1
    str2 = inFile.read()
    print str2
    print
    inFile.close()

def getHours(hours):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        hours[counter] = input('Enter hours worked per day')
        counter = countr + 1
    return hours

def getTotalHours(hours, totalHours):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        totalHours = totalHours + hours[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    return totalHours

def getWages(wages):
    wages = input('Enter your hourly wage.')
    return wages

def getTotalWages(totalHours, wages):
    totalWages = totalHours * wages
    print 'Your total pay due is:' , totalWages
    return totalWages

def readFromClock(clockHours):
    inFile = open('clockhours.txt', 'r')
    str1 = inFile.read()
    print str1
    str2 = inFile.read()
    print str2
    print
    inFile.close()

    while choice != '5':

        if choice == '1':
            readFromNext(nextWeek)
            print 'Upcoming schedules'


        if choice == '2':
            readFromLast(lastWeek)
            print 'Previous schedules'


        if choice == '3':
            hours = getHours(hours)
            totalHours = getTotalHours(hours, totalHours)
            wages = getWages(wages)
            totalWages = gettotalWages(totalHours, wages)
            print 'Paycheck calculator'

        if choice == '4':
            readFromClock(clockHours)
            print 'Clock in/out times'


main()
```

Comment: Also, choice is never used within the main() loop.

Comment: Ok, see that makes sense. Now, might be a stupid question but why isn't 'choice' used in main()?

Comment: `choice = raw_input('Enter 1 to 4 from menu.')` It is only assigned, but is never used.

Comment: Also, the parameters passed into your functions are required, but never used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect it to do? You have added many functions but they appear to be unused. You end up printing the menu over and over again because you are in the loop

```
while passWord == userId:
    ...
```

You have to do something with the `choice` variable and break out of that loop if you want anything else to happen.

For example:

```
choice = raw_input('Enter 1 to 4 from menu.')
if choice == 1:
    readFromNext(nextWeek)
elif choice == 2:
    readFromLast(lastWeek)
elif choice == 3:
    getTotalWages(totalHours, wages)
elif choice == 4:
    getHours(hours)
```

Obviously you will need to figure out which function maps to which user input, but currently you are not doing anything with the user's choice, merely asking them to choose over and over again with no control over the termination of the loop.

Comment: Ok I see it now. I didn't really understand why the loop kept going. This cleared it up! A lot more errors to fix but this is a start!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of `login` in your `while not` loop.

```
login = 'default'
while not (login == 'yes' or login == 'no'):
    print 'Please enter a yes or no'
    login = raw_input('Do you want to login?')
```

... for example. The way you currently have it is never going to end:

```
while not (login == 'yes' or login == 'no'):
    print
    print 'Please enter a yes or no'
```

This is conceptually identical as:

```
while True:
    if login == 'yes' or login == 'no':
        break
    print
    print 'Please enter a yes or no'
```

So if the login is never changed, it will never end.

Comment: Even after fixing using your guidance it still populates the menu options after user inputs selection.